# Land Use grib2 Table 4.212 download?

Tags: land-surface, gfs

The grib2 format has a field listed under table 4.212 giving the land use code.  Does anyone know where I can download data containing this field?

Comment: Seems to be quite hard to find such data. Ofter, input data are not available. If available, then one easily gets things like the land-sea mask. "Land use" ist hard. I found land use NetCDF files in our data archive but none in GRIB. We have a few "land cover" datasets. Maybe that's the same? https://cera-www.dkrz.de/WDCC/ui/cerasearch/entry?acronym=C2_NCEP_CO_LAND

Comment: https://www.esa-landcover-cci.org/ and/or https://www.visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/61004/new-land-cover-classification-maps may be helpful (I realize "land cover" and "land use" are different, but they can be related)